Volume of 4D tetrahedral "truncated prism"
Given this question about the volume of a right angular prism with a triangle base shape in 3D, I was curious, if the formula holds similarly for one dimension higher.
So, assume a tetrahedron with vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and volume $V$. WLOG embed it into one of the hyperplanes e.g. $v_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i, 0)$.
Then, define "vertical" height lines $h_1, h_2, h_3, h_4$ with $h_i = x_i^2 + y_i^2 + z_i^2$
Would the formula for the volume ($V_4$) of this "4D right angular truncated prism" simply be:
$$
V_4 = V\frac{h_1 + h_2 + h_3 + h_4}{4}
$$
Does anybody know of a textbook reference or similar reference for this problem?

I’m sure one can show that your answer is correct but I don’t understand why you need $h_i$’s to take that specific form. It’s true for any $h_i$’s.

It was just how the problem arose for me and I wanted to give a clear example. I agree with you that this would then be generalisable . Thanks for your answer btw, @Pranay.

I see, okay. If my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. It's customary to accept answers so as to settle the post.

I will consider the general $n$-dimensional case: the base is an $(n-1)$-simplex in the horizontal hyperplane ($x_n = 0$) with $n$ vertices $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, and vertex vertically above $v_i$ is $w_i = v_i + (0,\ldots,0,h_i)$ at height $h_i$.
Let us pick two base vertices, say $v_1$ and $v_2$ without loss of generality, and move the vertices $w_1$ and $w_2$ above them to new vertices $w_1'$ and $w_2'$ at heights $h_1-\epsilon$ and $h_2+\epsilon$ respectively for some $\epsilon>0$ (small enough so that all heights are still nonnegative). There is always a unique hyperplane which passes through $w_1', w_2',w_3,\ldots,w_n$, so the new vertices define a new truncated prism.
I claim that the volume of this new truncated prism is the same as the volume of the original truncated prism. This is illustrated for $n=2$ and $n=3$ below.
$n=2$:

$n=3$:

Proof of claim: Let $w_{12}$ be the midpoint of $w_1$ and $w_2$. Clearly, $w_{12}$ is also the midpoint of $w_1'$ and $w_2'$. Let $v_{12}$ be the projection of $w_{12}$ onto the horizontal hyperplane, i.e., $v_{12}$ is the midpoint of $v_1$ and $v_2$. Now, the change in the volume of the truncated prism is the difference in the volumes of the two $n$-simplices $\{w_1,w_1',w_{12},w_3,\ldots,w_n\}$ (red in the images) and $\{w_2,w_2',w_{12},w_3,\ldots,w_n\}$ (green in the images). But we know that
\begin{align}
&\mathrm{vol}_n(w_1,w_1',w_{12},w_3,\ldots,w_n)
\\
&= \frac1n \cdot \epsilon\cdot \mathrm{vol}_{n-1}(v_1,v_{12},v_3,\ldots,v_n)
\\
&= \frac1n \cdot \epsilon\cdot \mathrm{vol}_{n-1}(v_2,v_{12},v_3,\ldots,v_n)
\\
&= \mathrm{vol}_n(w_2,w_2',w_{12},w_3,\ldots,w_n).
\end{align}
Here, all the equalities follow from Cavalieri's principle in $n$ or $n-1$ dimensions. The claim follows. $\blacksquare$
If all $h_i$'s are the same, then we are done. If not, pick $i$ and $j$ such that $h_i \ge h_k \ge h_j$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$. Replace $(h_i,h_j) \to (h_i-\epsilon,h_j+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon = \frac{h_i-h_j}2 > 0$. By the claim above, the resulting truncated prism still has the same volume. After repeating this for at most $n/2$ steps, the difference between the max and min heights reduces by a fraction strictly less than $1$ (this fraction depends only on $n$). Repeating this indefinitely, we end up with a truncated prism with equal heights. Since the sum of all heights is preserved in each step, the final height is $h=\frac1n(h_1+\cdots+h_n)$. Therefore, the volume of the truncated prism is
$$
\mathrm{vol}_{n-1}(v_1,\ldots,v_n) \cdot h.
$$

Why do we know: $n^{-1} \bullet vol_{n-1} (v_1, v_{12}, v_3, ..., v_n)$ etc. ?

All those equalities follow from Cavalieri's principle. For example, in the first equality, you can fix $w_1$ and $w_1'$ and move the remaining vertices "vertically" without changing the volume of that $n$-simplex (this is Cavalieri's principle). We can move those vertices such that they are all in a hyperplane passing through $w_1$ and parallel to the horizontal hyperplane....

(cont'd)... Then, the volume of that $n$-simplex is simply $1/n$ times height times volume of the base $(n-1)$-simplex. The height is $\epsilon$ (that's the length of the segment $w_1 w_1'$) and the volume of the base is exactly the volume of the $(n-1)$-simplex $v_1,v_{12},v_3,\ldots,v_n$. The remaining equalities can be argued in a similar fashion.
